# How to check for presence of "Haptic Touch" on iPhone XR?

Tags: ios, iphone

Most modern iPhones have 3D Touch. For example, on iPhone Xs:

```
print("Force touch available: ", traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available)
// prints true
```

But iPhone SE, iPhone 5s, etc. don't have this:

```
print("Force touch available: ", traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available)
// prints false
```

iPhone Xʀ introduces "Haptic Touch", which seems like a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but with 3D Touch-like haptic feedback.

iPhone Xʀ behaves like the iPhone SE; that is, it doesn't support the force-related touch APIs:

```
print("Force touch available: ", traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available)
// prints false
```

Given this, what APIs are available to support Haptic Touch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555568/in-ios-how-can-i-distinguish-a-haptic-touch-from-a-long-press